# Is it possible to run two angular application with one is 1.6.4 and another one is 6.1?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Is  it possible to run two angular application with one is 1.6.4 and another one is 6.1? I also have global angular version 6.1. Can someone elaborate how it is possible or not?

Comment: What do you mean by *"globally"* ? Please take a few minutes to read through [ask] then edit question with a more detailed scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular cli 6.x will run all pre version you only will get a warning as version mismatch and a local angular cli version that related to your project will run;

```
Your global Angular CLI version (6.1.2) is greater than your local
version (1.6.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two main roads.

The first one is to use the ng-upgrade approach:  https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

With this approach, you can upgrade your angularjs components in order to be compatible with angular components, and you can downgrade your angular components in order to be compatible with angularjs.

A second road is to use web components, for an approach called micro apps or micro frontends. 
In this way you will have a root application which embeds two different applications, inside two different web components, in your case one for angularjs and another one for angular, which can communicate each other through the root application.

Comment: I have both angular cli 1.6.4 and 6.1 version? I have to ran both applications. But when I ran 1.6.4 one, there is an error like: your global angular CLI version greater than local version

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes!

You can run as many different version of angular versions as possible, just ensure that the port on which these apps are running are different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's possible. Take a look at this article: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

And you can upgrade or downgrade services and components between two frameworks.

An application with two angulars is called a `Hybrid Application`

You should know that there are two ways to bootstrap a Hybrid App:

1. Using [UpgradeModule](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeModule) - Bootstraps both the AngularJS (v1.6) and Angular (v6.1) frameworks in the Angular zone
2. Using [DowngradeModule](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeModule) - Bootstraps AngularJS outside of the Angular zone and keeps the two change detection systems separate.

I have tried both ways. And I recommend using `DowngradeModule` - it's better for performance and memory leaks.

If you google `angular hybrid` you will find a lot of articles and examples on github